# C# to VB.NET function

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm having a problem in this function in C#.
I want to convert it to VB.NET

This code is C#

```
public Frm_Sched()
{
    dayView1.NewAppointment += new Calendar.NewAppointmentEventHandler(dayView1_NewAppointment);
}

void dayView1_NewAppointment(object sender, Calendar.NewAppointmentEventArgs args)
{
    Calendar.Appointment m_Appointment = new Calendar.Appointment();

    m_Appointment.StartDate = args.StartDate;
    m_Appointment.EndDate = args.EndDate;
    m_Appointment.Title = args.Title;

    oApp.Add(m_Appointment);
}
```

How can I convert it to VB.NET? I want to call this event in my Form Load

```
Private Sub Frm_Sched_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ Please search before asking

Comment: Use [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) for code conversion, encapsulate the code in a method and call that in the load event rather than calling the event handler explicitly

Comment: What do you mean: *call this event*? Do you want to raise the event, or do you want to just call the event handler?

Answer (score 3):

A direct translation would be:

```
Public Sub New()
    AddHandler dayView1.NewAppointment, AddressOf dayView1_NewAppointment
End Sub

Private Sub dayView1_NewAppointment(sender As Object, args As Calendar.NewAppointmentEventArgs)
    Dim m_Appointment = New Calendar.Appointment()

    m_Appointment.StartDate = args.StartDate
    m_Appointment.EndDate = args.EndDate
    m_Appointment.Title = args.Title

    oApp.Add(m_Appointment)
End Sub
```

---

You can always use automatic translators like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), but they generally fail in some cases, like unsafe code (obviously) and event subscription.